# Undefined variable: atts

Tags: php, wordpress

how to fix this notice , it appear in wordpress site its about changing existed short code of some plugin with another that have the same feature plus some additions

error location 
wp-content/plugins/n-custom-point/n_custom_point.php:864

line 864 is

```
    'user_id'    => 'current',
```

some lines from this part

```
/*add_action('wp_head','override_cs_user_login');
function override_cs_user_login() {
    remove_shortcode(MYCRED_SLUG . '_my_balance');
    add_shortcode(MYCRED_SLUG . '_my_balance', 'mycred_my_balance_n');
}*/
add_shortcode('n_point_my_balance', 'mycred_my_balance_n');
function mycred_my_balance_n() {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
line 864    'user_id'    => 'current',
            'title'      => '',
            'title_el'   => 'h1',
            'balance_el' => 'div',
            'wrapper'    => 1,
            'formatted'  => 1,
            'type'       => MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY
        ), $atts, MYCRED_SLUG . '_my_balance' ) );

        $output = '';
        $total_point = 0;
        // Not logged in
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $user_id == 'current' )
            return $content;

        // Get user ID
        $user_id = mycred_get_user_id( $user_id );
```

Comment: As the message says `$atts` variable in the middle of the function `mycred_my_balance_n` doesn't exist. Where should it be defined?

Comment: sorry I am not programmer , mycred_my_balance_n exist only in these lines above, so can you tell me how to define it to avoid this notice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$atts` variable should be supplied to the shortcode function as follows:

```
function mycred_my_balance_n($atts) {
  ...
}
```

When you use the shortcode you can set it with variables. Any variable you set will override the default you set in the array.